# Should uranium hexoxide exist?

Tags: oxidation-state, transuranic-elements

This compound of uranium called [uranium hexoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium_hexoxide) or uranium (XII) oxide is a theoretical chemical compound. The uranium should have  an oxidation state of +12 ,the highest of any known chemical. The closest is the $\ce{[IrO4]+}$ cation with iridium having an oxidation state of +9 so this is obviously mind blowing. Does this compound exist or has it been synthesized yet,without it spontaneously decomposing?

Comment: See: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp102107n ... https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0009261400009581

Comment: The oxidation number may not be +$12$, if the oxygen atoms are part of peroxy groups ·O-O·, where their oxidation number is -$1$.

Comment: @maurice it's more complicated than that.  The references describe oxygen in multiple ligand states, including not only peroxide but also superoxide and even monovalent radical oxygen ($\ce{-O•}$).